Merging dlls into a single .exe with .NET framework 4.8 and doing it manually with no weaver
Merging dlls into a single .exe with wpf
based off this thread and commments
urprisingly easy! In short only three steps: 1. edit your .csproject and paste the provided lines 2. create a .cs file, paste the provided lines and auto resolve the missing assemblies 3. change the startup object to the file you just created. –
Boern
CommentedSep 7, 2016 at 15:06
how do i do this?
ive tried fody/costura to weave the dlls into the exe and ilmerge. the problem is im using .net framework and winforms, or WPF, im not sure which andn ot sure how to check, but I have a bunch of pdfium dlls that id like to embed in the exe.
i tried putting the code in .csproj but when i run         If assemblyName.CultureInfo.Equals(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) = False Then path = String.Format("{0}{1}", assemblyName.CultureInfo, path)
it crashes (but doesnt need a try catch to keep running the program) and when i debug to see the assemblyName.Name +.dll i see it only runs over files like xmlserializer and resources file, its not traversing the many dlls in the package folder.
i tried using old verions of fody/costura but the pdfium dlls dont bundle into the exe and ontop of that the exe doesnt work correctly after bundling
i tried everything here as per
Trying to embed extra dll in program
ive tried verbose logging to see why the dlls are unable to be included as part of the exe,

Pdfium loads a native DLL. This native DLL is not referenced by your program/project. It is just loaded explicitly. Since there is no reference to be resolved towards this native DLL, it is not automatically aware of whether to embed/unpack such a DLL to/from a resource. You have to help FC with regard to native DLLs.

but even with fody/costura the exe stops working after bundling and its unable to fully bundle all the dlls. yet it somehow knows to bring them into the new debug folder made but it refuses to include them. also imagaeMagick dlls arent being bundled.
id like to learn how to bundle just a single dll into an exe and from there i imagine i can bundle all off them

I don't understand why you think you need Fody to do any of this, unless you're trying to combine assemblies into your EXE that are already weaved.  I suspect you're doing something else, as a DLL that has already undergone weaving is just like any other DLL.

the issue is that pdfium_86x is referenced by the other library PdfiumSharp but i think its a "native dll" meaning its not a managed assembly. id like to tell the code that looks for pdfium_x86
using (var doc = new Pdifiumsharp.pdfdocument(pdfFilesList[currentPdfIndex]) and this is where i crash due to not having pdfium_86..dll
to look at the embedded pdfium_x86 dll somehow

`Build Action Embedded Resource:
When you set the Build Action of a file to Embedded Resource, it includes the file within the assembly's resources. However, this does not mean the native DLL becomes part of the executable code that can be directly loaded by the operating system.
Loading Native DLLs:
Native DLLs like pdfium_x86.dll need to exist as separate files on the file system where the operating system can locate and load them at runtime. They cannot be loaded directly from embedded resources within the .NET executable.`
looks like its just not possible?
